# API Platform - Subresources: Cannot use reference for lookup or graphLookup: dbRef references are not supported (MongoDB-Symfony6.2)

Tags: mongodb, api-platform.com, symfony6

I am currently working on programming a website using Symfony version 6.2 and API Platform in addition to MongoDB (version v6.0.3) in the database.

I try to use the Subresources and I followed the official documentation of the API Platform: https://api-platform.com/docs/core/subresources/

I tried to use exactly what is written on the documentation (this the code):

```
#[ApiResource(
    uriTemplate: '/companies/{companyId}/employees',
    operations: [ new GetCollection() ]
    uriVariables: [
        'companyId' => new Link(toProperty: 'company', fromClass: Company::class),
    ]
)]
class Employee
{
    #[MongoDB\Id()]
    private string $id;

    #[MongoDB\Field(type: Type::STRING)]
    private string $name;

    #[MongoDB\ReferenceOne(targetDocument: Company::class, inversedBy: "employees")]
    private ?Company $company;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

and for the Company class:

```
#[ApiResource]
class Company
{
    #[MongoDB\Id()]
    public string $id;

    #[MongoDB\Field(type: Type::STRING)]
    public string $name;

    #[MongoDB\ReferenceMany(targetDocument: Employee::class, mappedBy: "company")]
    /** @var Employee[] */
    #[Link(toProperty: 'company')]
    public $employees = [];
}
```

but while using the Postman to get the result from `/companies/{companyId}/employees`, this error message appears:

```
"Cannot use reference 'company' in class 'App\\Document\\Company' for lookup or graphLookup: dbRef references are not supported."
```

Is there any solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `storeAs: 'id'` in the relation reference

```
#[ApiResource(
    uriTemplate: '/companies/{companyId}/employees',
    operations: [ new GetCollection() ]
    uriVariables: [
        'companyId' => new Link(toProperty: 'company', fromClass: Company::class),
    ]
)]
class Employee
{
    #[MongoDB\Id()]
    private string $id;

    #[MongoDB\Field(type: Type::STRING)]
    private string $name;

    #[MongoDB\ReferenceOne(storeAs: 'id', targetDocument: Company::class, inversedBy: "employees")]
    private ?Company $company;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

And the Company class:

```
#[ApiResource]
class Company
{
    #[MongoDB\Id()]
    public string $id;

    #[MongoDB\Field(type: Type::STRING)]
    public string $name;

    #[MongoDB\ReferenceMany(storeAs: 'id', targetDocument: Employee::class, mappedBy: "company")]
    /** @var Employee[] */
    #[Link(toProperty: 'company')]
    public $employees = [];
}
```